# Do topoi have injective hulls?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, topos-theory, infinity-topos-theory

Recall that a topos $\mathcal I$ is [injective](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/injective+topos) (with respect to [embeddings](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric+embedding)) if and only if $\mathcal I$ is a retract of $Psh(C)$ for some finitely-complete $C$. Say that an embedding $f : \mathcal X \to \mathcal Y$ is [essential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_monomorphism) if for any geometric morphism $g : \mathcal Y \to \mathcal Z$, we have that $g$ is an embedding if and only if $gf$ is an embedding.

**Warning:** This notion of "essential" is *unrelated* to the notion of an [essential geometric morphism](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/essential+geometric+morphism).

**Question 1:** How can one characterize the essential embeddings of topoi?

**Question 2:** Does every topos $\mathcal X$ have an [injective hull](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/injective+envelope) $\mathcal I(\mathcal X)$?

That is, does $\mathcal X$ admit an essential embedding $\mathcal X \to \mathcal I(\mathcal X)$ for some injective topos $\mathcal I(\mathcal X)$?

Here all topoi are Grothendieck if you like. If you like, you may consider them all as $\infty$-topoi.

**Remarks:**

0. Every topos is a left exact localization of a presheaf topos, even of presheaves on a *free* finitely-complete cateogry. So there is always an embedding into an injective topos $\mathcal X \to \mathcal I$; the question is about ensuring the embedding is essential.
1. Since the injective topoi are basically the classifying topoi of essentially algebraic theories, the choice of an embedding $\mathcal X \to \mathcal I$ where $\mathcal I$ is injective may be thought of as a choice of a "language" in which to axiomatize the theory classified by $\mathcal X$ as a geometric theory. So question (2) is in some sense a question about "finding a canonical language" for the theory classified by a given topos.
2. "The" injective hull of $\mathcal X$, if it exists, is unique up to not-necessarily-unique isomorphism under $\mathcal X$ -- see Rmk 2.2(2) of [Adamek, Herrlich, Rosicky, and Tholen](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s000120200006).

Comment: I am not sure this is a *good question*, I really do not understand why the geometric morphism should be essential. Yet, a relevant paper should be Totally distributive toposes by
Rory B.B. Lucyshyn-Wright.

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti the reason the embedding should be essential is that that’s the usual definition of an injective hull. It picks out an injective thing into which X embeds which is _minimal_, and as such, unique up to isomorphism. My remark 1 above gives one reason why such a thing would be desirable for topoi in particular.

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti But if you have an alternate notion of "minimal embedding into an injective object" which might be interesting to consider, I'd love to hear about it!

Comment: I do not understand what is the connection between minimality and essentiality, or I find the analogy a bit stretched. There are more "direct ways" to say that the embedding is minimal, for example that all other embeddings factors along it.

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti It's not an analogy. I'm asking for a direct application of the standard theory of injective hulls to a particular category -- see e.g. the Adamek-Herrlich-Rosicky-Tholen article cited above. You seem to be saying you don't like the standard theory of injective hulls. I'd be very curious to hear how you'd suggest as an alternative! The condition "$X \to I$ is an embedding to an injective object and every embedding $X \to J$ with $J$ injective factors through an embedding $I \to J$ seems not to imply that $I$ is unique up to isomorphism.

Comment: The argument from essentiality to minimality is essentially contained in Rmk 2.2(2) of Adamek-Herrlich-Rosicky-Tholen, as cited above.

Comment: Note that the terminology "essential" is confusing here, since there is a standard notion of [essential geometric morphism](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/essential+geometric+morphism) that is, as far as I can see, unrelated.  I gather you're importing some standard terminology from elsewhere, but if so you may want to annotate it somehow to avoid confusion.

Comment: Oh thanks Mike for the clarification! Indeed I was misunderstanding!

Comment: You probably need to impose some restrictions on $g$. Indeed it follows from [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/176529/41291) that for any nontrivial subtopos $\mathcal X$ of $\mathcal Y$ there is another nontrivial subtopos $\mathcal X'$ of $\mathcal Y$ such that $\mathcal X\cap\mathcal X'$ is empty (that is, the trivial topos with single morphism). Then $\mathcal X$ will continue to embed into the pushout $\mathcal P=\varinjlim\left(\text{point}\leftarrow\mathcal X'\to\mathcal Y\right)$ while the map from $\mathcal Y$ to $\mathcal P$ will not be an embedding.

Comment: Here is some evidence from the dual notion: projective covers as irreducible surjections. This works as is in the category of compact Hausdorff spaces; in general, the correct notion seems to be that a surjection $f:\mathcal P\to\mathcal Q$ is irreducible if for any **closed** $i:\mathcal P'\hookrightarrow\mathcal P$, surjectivity of $fi$ implies that $i$ is an equivalence.